# What path does Ruby on Rails consider while importing CSV files work in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, csv-import

I have incorporated an import feature in my app. While developing it, I have given the path where it checks for a particular file while importing. But I don't understand how will that work when deployed on the web. Every user will have a different file that they should be able to upload. What path will it consider then?
Consider the following code:

```
 #This is the view file from where i upload the CSV.
    <h4>Import/Export (from/to CSV format)</h4>
    <input type="file" name="csv" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="import" value="Import from CSV"/>
          <br />
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export questions to CSV" >
```

The following is the controller that handles it:

```
 def import

questionnaire_id = (params[:id])
begin
    file_data = File.read(Rails.root.join('spec/features/import_export_csv_oss/'+params[:csv]))
    a = QuestionnaireHelper.get_questions_from_csv(file_data,params[:id])
    redirect_to edit_questionnaire_path(questionnaire_id.to_sym), notice: "All questions have been successfully imported!"
   rescue
  redirect_to edit_questionnaire_path(questionnaire_id.to_sym), notice: $ERROR_INFO
end
```

So, currently, it checks in the import_export_csv_oss folder for the file that I want to upload. In my development environment, I can put that file there. But when it's deployed on the web, will it work when a user tries to upload a file from his local machine?

Comment: Do you have some example code that demonstrates your concern? One way to handle this kind of scenerio is to store uploaded files to a location relative to your application code, e.g., `CSV.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', 'new_file.csv'), "wb") do |csv| ...`

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Comment: Okay I see what you are attempting; your current approach won't work. In your controller you are reading a file that already exists on the server, not what is passed up from the client.  I'd advise reading section 5.1 of the Rails' guide on form helpers (uploading files): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to save the file on your server and only import data, you should send the data with the local filepath as a parameter and header 'Content-Type' set to 'multipart/form-data'

```
def import
      data = CSV.read(filepath.tempfile, { encoding: "UTF-8", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all })
      #code to process and save it
end
```

This will create a ruby tempfile only valid for the request (unless you save it at a specified location) that you can read in memory.
Read more about tempfiles here
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

Here's an example request using curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "token: Xh7uHRUsnjVaaMd12" -X POST -F "parameter_1=5b71b02" -F "filepath=@/Users/mojo/Downloads/dyp.csv;type=text/csv" https://website/url
```